# Auto-size this div using only CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get the `<div class="audio-feed-wrapper">` tag to auto resize (width only) if there are more `<li>` tags inside of it, using only CSS. I'm willing to change some HTML IF I must to get it to work. It also needs to be centered on the page, at all times, no matter the width of it.

There is javascript, which is too long to post here, that is adding styling to some of the HTML tags, so it's best to look at my jsfiddle, but I will put the code below: http://jsfiddle.net/Draven/FpTp6/4/

The jQuery plugin that is being used it jCarouselLite: http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <section id="main" class="main">
        <div class="audio-feed-wrapper">
            <div class="arrow-prev"></div>
            <div class="audio-feed-list">
                <ul class="audio-feed">
                    <li><a href="?audio=5" title="Test Title 3"><img src="Test.Title.3.jpg" alt="Test Title 3" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="?audio=4" title="Test Title 2"><img src="Test.Title.2.jpg" alt="Test Title 2" /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="arrow-next"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/** General **/
 * {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
html {
    font-size:100%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
html, body, .nav {
    height:100%;
}
body {
    background:#000;
    font:100 1em/1 Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
    color:#fff;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none outside
}
/*Centers entire page*/
 #wrapper {
    position:relative;
    /*Puts container in front of distance*/
    clear:left;
    max-width:580px;
    min-width:417px;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:0;
    text-align:left;
}
/*End of centering entire page*/

/*main*/
[class|=main], .main {
    font-family: TimesNewRoman, "Times New Roman", Times, Baskerville, Georgia, serif;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:18px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
.main {
    margin:0 auto;
}
/*media*/
 .audio-feed-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    top:10px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    max-width: 480px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 4px
}
.audio-feed li {
    margin-right: 5px;
    line-height: 90px;
}
.audio-feed img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 120px;
    height: 90px
}
```

Comment: http://plugins.learningjquery.com/jcarousellite/#responsive-carousels

Comment: I don't think how that's going to help me since I still need it to function. But thank you for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Well. There is a pretty simple way to center two elements, both with an ID, relative to one another.

```
function getWidth(id)
{
    return document.getElementById(id).offsetWidth;
}

function centerWidth(id1,id2)
{
    return ((getWidth(id2)/2)-(getWidth(id1)/2));
}
```

It is rather simple math. find the width of both elements then dividing each with by 2 and subtract the difference (smallest from greatest value).

HTML could look like this

```
<div id="x" width="500">
    <div id="y" width="350">
        something...
    </div>
</div>
```

Then set the element

```
function setElm()
{
    var elm = document.getElementById(x);
    elm.style.position = "absolute";    // Can be set in a CSS file as #x{position:absolute;}
    elm.style.left = centerWidth("x","y") + "px"; //This is actualy CSS generated by JS. So if the width is dynamic, the elements will still be centered correctly. Remember to add the +"px".
}
```

Now I don't understand why the div does not expand, unless there is a "max-width" somewhere?

--EDIT--

You could try to give the div in question ( div class="audio-feed-wrapper") an ID e.g. audio-feed-wrapper.

```
function setElm()
{
    var elm = document.getElementById(x);
    elm.style.position = "absolute";    // Can be set in a CSS file as #x{position:absolute;}
    elm.style.left = centerWidth("x","y") + "px"; //This is actualy CSS generated by JS. So if the width is dynamic, the elements will still be centered correctly. Remember to add the +"px".

    var x = document.getElementById("audio-feed-wrapper");
    var y = x.getElementsByTagName("li");

    width = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<y.length; i++)
    {
         width = width + y[i].offsetWidth;
         // now I don't know if .offsetWidth works here, I'm just guessing here.
    }
    x.style.width = width + "px";
}
```

Comment: As you can see in the JSFiddle, the div is expanded by default. Since there is only two `<li>` tags (or images) it should shrink to fit around them, with no extra space, and then expand as more `<li>` are added.

Comment: The jCarouselLite javascript file is making the `<div>` expand. It calculates how many images you want visible (in my case 6) and the width of them (120px).

Comment: How about my EDIT section?